# Событие CheckBox

Tags: c#

В отдельном классе создаются `CheckBox` и выводятся на форме.

Вот класс:

```
class CheckBoxCreate
{
    CheckBox[] check;
    private Form cont;

    public CheckBoxCreate( Form cont )
    {
        this.cont = cont;
    }

    public void CreateCheck()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo( @"12" );
        FileInfo[] inf = dir.GetFiles( "*.txt" );
        check = new CheckBox[inf.Length];

        for ( int i = 0; i < inf.Length; i++ )
        {
            check[i] = new CheckBox();
            check[i].Visible = true;
            check[i].Parent = cont;
            check[i].Location = new Point( 200, 5 + i * 50 );
            check[i].Name = i.ToString();
            check[i].Text = "Чекбокс номер " + i;
            check[i].Checked = true;
            check[i].Width = 120;
            check[i].Height = 40;
            check[i].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(check_Change);
            cont.Controls.Add( check[i] );
        }
    }

    public void check_Change( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {

    }
}
```

Все хорошо работает и выводится правильно.
На форме есть кнопка, при клике она должна вызвать событие `check_Change` из
класса, чтобы снять все флажки с созданных `CheckBox`.
Как лучше сделать, куда копать? 
Это просто наброски, чтобы потом все соединить и написать программу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Снятие чека с чекбокса - это причина, вызов события (и всех его обработчиков, в вашем случае - `check_Change`) - это следствие. Обратное - неверное. Т.е. ручной вызов метода `check_Change` никак не влияет на состояние чекбокса.

Сменить состояние чекбокса можно заданием значения свойства Checked. Задать его для всех чекбоксов на форме можно примерно так:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var checkbox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
    {
        checkbox.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

В вашем случае вы и так отслеживаете созданные чекбоксы, так что достаточно запомнить ссылку на использованный CheckBoxCreate в поле формы, и в обработчике кнопки воспользоваться им для перебора чекбоксов:

поле класса формы:

```
СheckBoxCreate checkBoxCreate;
```

код создания чекбоксов:

```
this.checkBoxCreate = new CheckBoxCreate(this);
this.checkBoxCreate.CreateCheck();
```

по клику на кнопку:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.checkBoxCreate.CheckAll();
}
```

где

```
class CheckBoxCreate
{
    ...
    public void CheckAll()
    {
        foreach (var checkbox in this.check)
        {
            checkbox.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас переделаю.

Comment: Все спасибо разобрался, все работает, сделал в двух направлениях снимать и ставить галочки. Я искал как раз перебор списка контролов, чтобы потом присвоить им Checked false,true. Но увы не нашел. Так что спасибо помогли.